# Como pongo la imagen al lado de una tabla con bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, css, html5, bootstrap

Estoy intentando poner las imágenes a la derecha de una tabla, pero estas se sitúan arriba o abajo. Estoy intentando ponerlas para cuando haces `hover` sobre el elemento de la lista la imagen aparezca. Hay 3 imágenes sin visibilidad porque solo va a ser una la que se mostrará al principio y luego a la vez que va pasando por los `<li>` irá mostrando una u  otra imagen. Adjunto foto de como me sale con mi código e incluyo también el propio código.

Este es el resultado que se me queda a mi con el código insertado, lo que necesito es que se queden las imágenes a la derecha de la tabla en la misma alineación.

[image: imagen]

html:

```
<div id="servicios">
       <h2>SERVICIOS QUE OFREZCO</h2>
           <div id="servOfrecidos">
               <div id="lista">
                <img id="imgServicios1" src="./img/ciberseg.jpg">
               <img id="imgServicios2" src="./img/codigo.jpg">
               <img id="imgServicios3" src="./img/securityy.jpg">
               <img id="imgServicios4" src="./img/servidores.jpg">
                <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                      <li class="list-group-item">Creaci&oacute;n de p&aacute;ginas WEB desde CERO</li>
                      <li class="list-group-item">Edici&oacute;n de p&aacute;ginas WEB ya creadas</li>
                      <li class="list-group-item">Protecc&oacute;n de la red</li>
                      <li class="list-group-item">Instalaci&oacute;n, programaci&oacute;n y mantenimiento del Servidor</li>
                </ul>
               </div>
           </div>
    </div>
```

css:

```
#servicios{
   
}
#servOfrecidos{
    margin-top: 3.5vw;
}
#lista{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 15vw;
    width: 25vw;
}
#imgServicios1{
    margin-right: 15vw;
    height: 15vw;
    width: 22vw;
    float: right;
    visibility: hidden;
}
#imgServicios2{
    margin-right: 15vw;
    height: 15vw;
    width: 22vw;
    float: right;
    visibility: hidden;
}
#imgServicios3{
    margin-right: 15vw;
    height: 15vw;
    width: 22vw;
    float: right;
    visibility: hidden;
}
#imgServicios4{
    margin-right: 0vw;
    height: 15vw;
    width: 22vw;
    float: right;
    visibility: ;
}
```

Comment: No está claro el planteo, tampoco imágen adjunta, pero por lo que vi, tendrías que hacerlo por JavaScript, en vez de un hover usar por ejemplo un eventlistener onmouseover que cambie el display de la imágen..

Comment: Puedes adjuntar el preview de lo que llevas hecho?

Answer (score 1):

Si usas `bootstrap` apenas necesitas usar CSS externo, por la cantidad de clases que ya tiene y para evitarte el coste extra que supone mantenerlo.

`Bootstrap` tiene casi todo lo que puedas necesitar si lo conoces bien.

En cuanto al `hover` de las imagenes, te recomiendo hacerlo en javascript.

Adjunto un fragmento (`snippet`) básico aproximado de lo que creo que quieres.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <div class="container">
      <h2>SERVICIOS QUE OFREZCO</h2>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col" id="servicios">
          <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
            <li class="list-group-item" onmouseover="this.classList.add('active');imgServicios.src='https://www.sccenlared.es/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/Soluciones-de-Ciberseguridad-1100x640.jpg';" onmouseout="this.classList.remove('active');imgServicios.src='';">Creaci&oacute;n de p&aacute;ginas WEB desde CERO</li>
            <li class="list-group-item" onmouseover="this.classList.add('active');imgServicios.src='https://conceptodefinicion.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/codigo-.jpg';" onmouseout="this.classList.remove('active');imgServicios.src='';">Edici&oacute;n de p&aacute;ginas WEB ya creadas</li>
            <li class="list-group-item" onmouseover="this.classList.add('active');imgServicios.src='https://blog.tmcnet.com/blog/rich-tehrani/uploads/lan-security.jpg';" onmouseout="this.classList.remove('active');imgServicios.src='';">Protecci&oacute;n de la red</li>
            <li class="list-group-item" onmouseover="this.classList.add('active');imgServicios.src='https://www.racksolutions.com/news//app/uploads/AdobeStock_267084326.jpg';" onmouseout="this.classList.remove('active');imgServicios.src='';">Instalaci&oacute;n, programaci&oacute;n y mantenimiento del Servidor</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <img id="imgServicios" class="img-fluid" src="" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**Cambios realizados:**

- He quitado todo el CSS externo
- He creado un `<div class="container">` que engloba todo el codigo, porque mantiene unos margenes relativos adecuados en los navegadores. Si lo quieres extender del todo cambia `container` por `container-fluid`.
- A continuación he puesto la cabecera de la página `<h2>` para que quede por encima de la siguiente estructura de filas y columnas.
- A continuación he creado un `<div class="row">` para indicarle que ahora viene una fila completa, de punta a punta de su contenedor, que en este caso es el div `container`

Después he puesto tu código con las siguientes modificaciones:

- He agregado la clase `col` al div con el id `servicios`, definiendo una columna dentro de la fila creada en el div anterior `row`
- Dentro de esta columna esta el `list-group` con la lista de los servicios ofrecidos. He eliminado los divs `servOfrecidos` y `lista` pues ya no hay CSS externo.
- En cada `list-group-item`he agregado el código javascript usando los eventos `onmouseover` y `onmouseout`.  Dicho código hace dos cosas: 1) Cambia la clase del elemento `list-group-item` activándola o desactivándola agregando o eliminando la clase `active` de bootstrap, la cual hace que el elemento muestre un background de color azul por defecto. 2) Cambia el atributo `src` de la imagen que luego irá en la siguiente columna de la fila. (he usado imagenes de google images para ello, tu pon las que quieras).
- Luego viene el cierre del `div` de la primera columna y la apertura del siguiente div de columna así `<div class="col">`.  Si se usa la clase `col` a secas bootstrap la organiza a partes iguales a lo largo de la fila, aunque es preferible usar columnas más personalizadas según el tamaño del dispositivo que va a abrir la página, como `col-md-x`, `col-sm-x`, etc.  Es decir, si solo usas `col` varias veces (no solo dos como en este caso) te hará todas las columnas iguales (al menos en pantalla completa).
- Dentro de esta nueva columna he puesto un solo elemento de imagen, el cual irá cambiando su atributo `src`según pasees por encima de los elementos `list-group-item` gracias al javascript anterior ya descrito.
- Finalmente he cerrado los divs de la columna, la fila y el container.

Encontrarás toda la información que necesitas sobre bootstrap 5 y las clases usadas en este código en su [página web](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/introduction/).

**Recomendaciones finales:**

- No uses `&acutes` para los acentos, escríbelos tal cual y te recomiendo que uses un editor con soporte para UTF8 para ello y agreges `<meta charset="utf-8">` dentro del tag `<head>` del documento.  Con ello ganarás claridad y tus páginas seran más amigables para el SEO.
- Usando `bootstrap` evita los CSS externos. Tan solo cuando sean estrictamente necesarios (como puede ser un cambio de colores radical), pero para temas de posicionamiento y distribución y disposición del contenido confia en bootstrap y no saldrás defraudado pues evitarás muchos problemas en todos tipo de dispositivo.
- Invierte tiempo en su [manual](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/introduction/) y juega con el usando herramientas online, como por ejemplo en el siguiente enlace, donde encontrarás el mismo código del fragmento que viene a continuación:  [enlace](https://jsfiddle.net/dLpf89g2/)